# Dynatree is expended on loading

Tags: jquery, dynatree

I am creating a dynatree with NODE option expand = false. but when I view the tree, it shows all expended at the beginning itself. How to get tree with all collapse in initial stage.
below is my code

```
$(function(){
            // Attach the dynatree widget to an existing <div id="tree"> element
            // and pass the tree options as an argument to the dynatree() function:
            $("#tree").dynatree({
                onActivate: function(node) {
                    // A DynaTreeNode object is passed to the activation handler
                    // Note: we also get this event, if persistence is on, and the page is reloaded.
                    //alert("You activated " + node.data.key);
                },
                persist: false,
                checkbox: true,
                generateIds: false,

                classNames: {
                    checkbox: "dynatree-checkbox",
                    expanded: "dynatree-expanded"
                },
                selectMode: 3,
                children: {!JsonString},
                onSelect: function(select, node) {
                    // Get a list of all selected nodes, and convert to a key array:
                    var selKeys = $.map(node.tree.getSelectedNodes(), function(node){
                        return node.data.key;
                    });
                    jQuery(document.getElementById("{!$Component.selectedKeys}")).val(selKeys.join(", "));

                    // Get a list of all selected TOP nodes
                    var selRootNodes = node.tree.getSelectedNodes(true);
                    // ... and convert to a key array:
                    var selRootKeys = $.map(selRootNodes, function(node){
                        return node.data.key;
                    });
                },

            });

        });
```

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer on your question? Please read [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 1):

In my dynatree I use AJAX on init and expand whole tree, but maybe this modification of my code will help you:

```
onPostInit: function(isReloading, isError) {
    this.$tree.dynatree('getRoot').visit(function(node){
        node.expand(false);
    });
}
```